# Parquet format: Is it useful when fetching all the columns?

Tags: hadoop, parquet

I've heard recommendations to use the Parquet format file when only some of the columns of the data set are fetched (because of its columnar storage format).

But what about fetching all the columns? If I have a structured dataset saved in parquet file in hdfs and want to fetch all the columns, is there any benefit to use parquet file?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Having said that, your question feels a bit broad, so dont feel surprised when not many answers come in.